# rqt_graph font too large

Tags: ros, rqt-graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I've been progressing through the tutorials, but have hit a snag with rqt_graph.  On my high-dpi screen (3200x1800, 262ppi) the font used for node/topic labels is far too large and obscures important details of the graph.  Is there a way to lower the font size?

Screenshots follow:

At my normal resolution (3200x1800):
[image]

...and at a lower resolution (1920x1080):
[image]

Thanks for your help!

-Jack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190133/rqt_graph-font-too-large/) by [JSR694](https://answers.ros.org/users/20011/jsr694/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23427/antonio/) on 2015-11-18**:
I would like just to mention that I have the very same problem, and I do think it would be important to address it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the tool currently has no feature to change font size and only remedy will be is someone writes a patch. See http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph for the package's issue tracker where you can send a patch (pull request on github).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) on 2015-11-19**:
Only as a comment. It would be nice if it were possible also move nodes and topics, when the project is to large, it is impossible to see the connections using rqt_grap.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with @130s. Only as a suggestion: Later on, when you get a better grasp of ROS, I suggest you to check [node_manager](http://wiki.ros.org/node_manager_fkie). It allows you to run your projects, load your launcher files and launch your nodes, as well as monitor your topics and subscriptions. I think this is a pretty nice tool.

---

Originally posted by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) with karma: 123 on 2015-11-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1